# Group permissions for a website using spring security - design query

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am creating a Grails website where users will have access to the resources they create. Till here everything is clear to me. I define `ROLE_USER` and lock down my controllers and actions using the `Config.groovy` file.

The issue I am facing is that I have requirement to support group of users such that some resources created by a user can be edited/updated/deleted by other users of the same group. How do I associate a user with a "group" in spring security, what is the design/library I should use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is to have your users' roles (the authorizations) come from the database. Once that is the case, you can then easily adjust the roles a user (or set of users) has and create/remove them on the fly. The docs have some pretty good info on how to get the roles to come from the database, so I won't go any more into that here.

Once the dynamic roles are in place, however, you still need to be able to connect roles to the objects that are created. There are essentially two ways you can go about doing this:

1. Access Control Lists
2. Custom logic

Depending on the granularity you need and the flexibility you want, one option may be more appealing than another.

Access Control Lists essentially allow you to have a permission mapping between each user and each entity instance. As you can imagine, it's a fair bit of overhead and can perform poorly if you have a large number of entities and users.

Putting together your own logic, on the other hand, is much more flexible because you can set up your own scheme to connect entity instances or entity classes to users and their roles.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that spring-security provides such functionality out of the box so you will have to do that manually.
For each domain class that you this kind of functionality, store the user name of current logged in user

```
def authenticateService

def user = authenticateService.principal() 
entity.setUser(user?.getUsername())
```

Then in the update/delete method of the contoller you should check if the role of the current logged in user matches 
the role of the user that created the entity. If you have a match you should proceed with the update/delete otherwise throw an exception
/redirect the user to an error page

As role you can use the spring security roles or you can create a property on the user object you have created

Comment: Issue with using roles anytime someone starts a "group" a new role need to be assigned dynamically to this group of users which does not sound feasible. Did I make sense?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand. It seems to me that this is the normal procedure when a new role is introduced, it should be assigned to some users.